# In VIM editor how can some specific words be always highlighted?

Tags: vim

A few words such as **TODO** remain highlighted always in VIM.

Can I add some custom words to this list which I want to be highlighted always?

Comment: how is this unclear what he's asking?

Comment: maybe better suited for speruser

Comment: @bolov he was asking how to customize highlighting in vim. (how to create hi-group and use that group to hi text)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Todo is a **syntax group**, `:h group-name` to check detail.

If you want to make some words/text highlighted, you can either edit syntax file, or create your own **hi-groups** (`:h highlight-groups`) and add match.

For example:

You can do `match todo /!Important!/` to let text `!Important!` to be highlighted in same way as `TODO`. Or:

```
hi! Important ctermbg=red guibg=red
```

this will create a hi-group called `Important`.

Then you add match:

```
:match Important /!Important!/
```

this will highlight text `!Important!` in the way you defined in the group.

You could also add those lines in your vimrc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `match` command to do that. E.g. if you want to highlight a word (say `foo`):

```
:match <highlight-group> "foo"
:match error "foo"  // highlights foo as red.
:match Tag "foo"    // highlights foo to orange
```

Use `:highlight` to get more info on highlight group. Also you can get more info about match using `:help match`.